# AngularJS loop and check the checkboxes in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a loop in which data comes from 2 different objects

looping (ng-repeat) over list of available list of data , I have my ng-model saving and working perfectly.

Say in a given loop   $index starts at 0 ...

So I figured that some type of `isExist` that I found would work :/

problem is my data in the saved object is not matching up in the loop for one thing....

Not sure how to really do this

```
 <input ng-checked="isExist(vm.directiveassoc[$index].DirectiveId) !=-1"
```

As I loop over the Id that should be checked are 1 and 5

```
(value = {{vm.directiveassoc[$index].DirectiveId}} )
<input ng-checked="isExist(vm.directiveassoc[$index].DirectiveId) !=-1" ng-model="vm.question.directive[directive.Id]" type="checkbox" id="{{directive.Id}}"
```

[image]

Comment: Not really sure that I understand your question... Can you specify with a code sample or clearer explanation.

Comment: Did you try to omit the `[ ]`-brackets around `[DirectiveId]` ?

Comment: Ok  omitted brackets , let me edit the question

Comment: why you set `.` after `index`? is `DirectiveId` is params from object? if not you have to change it to `[$index]["DirectiveId"]`

Comment: notice that value = 1  and value = 5 ,  as it found those based on the $index  ,  but that is not the correct order   ,   0-5 on real list ,  and then what is saved to database and pulled up is then smaller list of objects..

Comment: Maybe you want to show how your data looks like.